# Regex for a numerical value in which digit should not start with 0

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex in which the digit cannot start with 0. Regex should not allow “.0” in the sequencing.
Example: `1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0`

However, this sequence is allowed
Examples: `1, 1.10, 1.10.1`

The regular expression I have tried is this `([1-9]|([1-9]+)+(\.[1-9]+))$`

and the output is that it fails till 2 "." fails after that for eg it will fail till `1.0.0`. However it matches at `1.0.0.2`

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but you should know that `1.10.101.11.10.1` isn't a decimal value An neither is `1.1.0`. Both are using digits and dots, but that doesn't make it a decimal number. You need to be more precise.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: Still not a question. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: tried this so far ([1-9]|([1-9]+)+(\.[1-9]+))$

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: it fails till 2 "."  fails after that for eg it will fail till 1.0.0. However it matches at 1.0.0.2

Comment: Shouldn't 1.0.0 and 1.0.0.2 be invalid, though (since a . can't be immediately followed by a 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on the answer would be

```
([1-9][0-9]*)(\.([1-9][0-9]*))*
```

It will match a selection exactly as the poster describes, a series of integers separated by periods where each integer does not begin with a 0.

If the application requires the selection to be at the start of a line, I'd suggest adding a carat ( ^ ) as the first character in the regex.

Comment: In the interest of helping OP understand what's going on here, I've laid out the line I provided in pseudo code below.

Find a number between 1 - 9
Find zero or more numbers between 0 - 9
Loop
    Check for a period. If one is found, repeat the beginning code to 
    search for a non-zero digit and zero or more numbers between 0 - 9. 
    If the above fails, stop looping.